# Sails: ObjectId types without using associations

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm aware of the association feature of Waterline, however for this specific application I do not want to use it (I don't want the related models returned in my JSON-- I only want their ObjectIds).

Is there a way to create a field on my model that is typed as ObjectId without using associations?

Answer (score 0):

You can return the objectId of an association by simply not populating it.

If I have an Owner with Pets.

Owner.Find(1).populate('pet).exec(...) will return User with pet as an object.

If you just use

Owner.Find(1).exec(...) will return User with pet as objectId

Comment: a kitty dies every time you down vote without a comment. I'm happy to change or even remove my answer if the person who downvoted wants to explain.